# Add new endpoints to OpenID configuration to an Auth0 app?

Tags: openid, openid-connect, auth0

Can i add custom scope, custom endpoints and some other fields to the Provider Metadata (.well-known/openid-configuration) in Auth0 app? any tutorial/example to do that?
for example, I would like to add user_premiuminfo endpoint to the openid-configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Endpoints are not designed to be extended like this:

- Think of the Open Id Connect Provider as toolbox software that does the really hard part of signing users in and externalising this complexity from your UIs and APIs.
- If you want custom endpoints then develop them as normal APIs that accept tokens. This is much easier to extend without blocking issues. It is also a portable solution that does not depend on vendor specific capabilities.

Custom scopes are supported by most providers and there may be an option to include these in metadata. In the below screenshot Okta includes default scopes in metadata.

[Custom Scopes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWpbs.png)[image]

If you want to expose an extended user info endpoint then it usually makes sense to build a User Info API. Think about whether fields are product specific. By all means use an Extended User Info scope and include it in a consent screen for the end user if you want.

But I would avoid adding product specific user data to the OIDP, since it is dilfficult to manage there. My [User Data Write Up](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/02/user-data) may help you to think about a solution that will work best.